# match any newline character except the ones between delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

I have given the following CSV file:

```
"A";"B
C";"D"
"E";"F"
"G
H"
```

And I need to get rid of newline characters that are placed in the text, except the ones placed directly between two delimiters (double quotes `""` in that case). Meaning only newline characters, that are the only sign between two double quotes (`"\n"`) should be present in the file.

The idea is to have a regex, that will:

**Find all new lines characters, except the ones between double quotes** (except the ones in the end of the line, as each line always starts and finishes with a double quote) and replace them by a space.

So the result of processing abovementioned file should be:

```
"A";"B C";"D"
"E";"F"
"G H"
```

So in other words, regex to find new lines characters between delimiters should:

**Find all `\n`, except `"\n"`**

I tried the following regex: `[^"\n"][\n]` to match every `\n` except `"\n"`, but testing this in Sublime Text 2 it selects the wanted new line character, but also a single character before it:

[image]

Which means that when I replace those found places with space, it will also replace the `B` and `G` characters, which is not expected.

I would also like to mention that I will use that Regex to perform replacement operation in C# code.

Do you have any idea how to make this working as I want ?

**EDIT 2016-07-14**:

I tried what **OmegaMan** proposed below.
It works fine for the case I specified above, however I didn't spot that it may came across multiple lines in the file. Example:

Given CSV file (referred as "pathToTheExampleFile" later in C# code):

```
"A";"B
C";"D"
"E";"F";"Part1
Part2
Part3
";
```

Using **OmegaMan**'s solution in the code, I get this result:

```
"A";"B C";"D"
"E";"F";"Part1 Part2
Part3
";
```

Whereas it is expected to be:

```
"A";"B C";"D"
"E";"F";"Part1 Part2 Part3  ";
```

However, after executing **OmegaMan**'s Replace operation three times, simply like that:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(@"pathToTheExampleFile");

string pattern = @"(?<=\x22[^\x22\r\n]+)([\r\n]+)";

var result = Regex.Replace(data, pattern, " ");

result = Regex.Replace(result, pattern, " ");

result = Regex.Replace(result, pattern, " ");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I get exactly the result I want. So it's multiline matching what is needed.
I don't see any other cases in which the regex may not work.

If you have any idea how to modify the regex, would be appreciated.

**EDIT 2016-07-15:**

I have to add that it works adding this ugly solution:

```
while (Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern))
{
    data = Regex.Replace(data, pattern, " ");
}
```

In the end, `data` contains expected string. It's very ugly, but I'm sure it's doable somehow with the regex.

Comment: Try [`(?<="[^"]*)\r?\n(?!")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%22%5b%5e%22%5d*)%5cr%3f%5cn(%3f!%22)&i=%22A%22%3b%22B%0d%0aC%22%3b%22D%22%0d%0a%22E%22%3b%22F%22%0d%0a%22G%0d%0aH%22&r=+).

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead based regex to search:

```
\n(?!")
```

and replace it by:

```
" "
```

`\n(?!")` will match any `\n` that are not followed by a double quote.

[RegEx Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cn(%3F!%22)&i=%22A%22%3B%22B%0D%0AC%22%3B%22D%22%0D%0A%22E%22%3B%22F%22%0D%0A%22G%0D%0AH%22&r=%20)

Answer (score 1):

By using a non consuming look behind to verify that there is an open quoted text,  this will do the job and replace the following `\r\n` with a space:

```
string data = "\"A\";\"B\r\nC\";\"D\"\r\n\"E\";\"F\"\r\n\"G\r\nH\"";

string pattern = @"(?<=\x22[^\x22\r\n]+)([\r\n]+)";

Regex.Replace(data, pattern, " " )
```

*Note that `\x22` is an escape for `"`.*

Replace returns this:

```
"A";"B C";"D"
"E";"F"
"G H"
```

Comment: Thanks. That is almost working. Consider file: http://pastebin.com/i2pa5Lq9
The result should of your Replace is: http://pastebin.com/YkWTT1sV, whereas I expect: http://pastebin.com/QjsEiy9r
What's interesting it if I execute Replace with the pattern you gave three times, it gives the expected result. So it's just a matter of matching all such cases somehow...

Comment: @DawidSibinski Update your question to add to the examples of failure lines on the first and second pass. In looking at it, it appears there are situations which cross **multiple** lines...and that would need to be a whole new regex pattern. This pattern only speaks to the rules you **initially** provided. Are there any other failure points?

Comment: I modified my post.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest easy to implement looping instead of complex regular expression:

```
private static String trimNewLines(String value) {
  if (null == value)
    return value;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.Length);

  Boolean inQuotation = false;

  foreach (char ch in value) {
    if (ch == '"')
      inQuotation = !inQuotation;

    if (inQuotation || ch != '\r' || ch != '\n')
      sb.Append(ch);
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}

...

String result = trimNewLines(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\MyData.csv"));
```

Comment: Do you think looping is faster than regex matching? I work with files with 500k - 1 million lines.

Comment: @DawidSibinski: Usually looping is *faster*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string pattern = @"([^\x22])(\r\n)+|(;\x22)\r\n";
string result = Regex.Replace(data, pattern, "$1$3 ");
```

I got

```
"A";"B C";"D"
"E";"F";"Part1 Part2 Part3 "
"G G2 G3";"H";" I I2 I3 "
```

Fot this input:

```
"A";"B
C";"D"
"E";"F";"Part1
Part2
Part3
"
"G
G2
G3";"H";"
I

I2

I3
"
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/uc538C